# Javascript Sum Function: How Do I Get Decimals in the Output?

Tags: javascript, sum, decimal

I've got a calculator tool that I'm using for a custom project that involves price quoting. I've gotten the basic functionality of adding the numbers in the input fields and totaling them up nicely.

As this is a price-quoting tool and not all of the numbers that are being added are whole, I need the output to display with two decimal places. It currently only displays a two-digit number, and that number actually rounds down. I'm sure it's something super-easy, but I can't figure it out.

[Here's the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H0psTW2cRiwR9POpWLG9?p=preview) (and associated code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

form {
display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.sum= () => 
 document.getElementById('result').value=
   Array.from(
     document.querySelectorAll('#majors_01,#majors_02,#majors_03,#majors_04,#majors_05,#majors_06,#majors_07')
   ).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)||0.00)
   .reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="majors_01_jerseys" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select id="majors_01_jerseys" onchange="document.majors_01_jerseys.majors_01.value=this.value;">
<option value="" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/18/1852B/large-54.jpg">Select a Jersey Model</option>
<option value="30.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/17/1751B/large-4P.jpg">Teamwork 1751B</option>
<option value="21.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/17/1755B/large-1.jpg">Teamwork 1755B</option>
<option value="27.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/17/1757B/large-15.jpg">Teamwork 1757B</option>
<option value="27.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/18/1825B/large-1.jpg">Teamwork 1825B</option>
<option value="29.90" data-src="http://www.majesticathletic.com/store/productimages/details/10754_columbia_blue_l_z.jpg">Majestic Cool Base 684Y</option>
<option value="32.54" data-src="http://www.uesports.com/imgrep/12107/image-440-0.jpg">UE B0173 (fully braided)</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_01" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_01"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#majors_01_jerseys").on('change', function(){
    $("#swap").attr("src", $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-src"));
});
</script>

</form>

<form name="majors_02_graphics" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_02_graphics.majors_02.value=this.value">
<option value="">Select Front Graphics Options</option>
<option value="2.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Silkscreen (one-color) - $2.75</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Silkscreen (two-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="4.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Silkscreen (three-color) - $4.75</option>
<option value="2.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Silkscreen (one-color) - $2.75</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Silkscreen (two-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="4.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Silkscreen (three-color) - $4.75</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Heat Press (one-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="7.50" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Heat Press (two-color) - $7.50</option>
<option value="11.25" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Heat Press (three-color) - $11.25</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Heat Press (one-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="7.50" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Heat Press (two-color) - $7.50</option>
<option value="11.25" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Heat Press (three-color) - $11.25</option>
</select>

$<input type="text" id="majors_02" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_02"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_03_numbers_front" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_03_numbers_front.majors_03.value=this.value">
<option value="">Front Numbers?</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">No - $0</option>
<option value="2.25" onkeyup="sum();">Yes (one-color) - $2.25</option>
<option value="7.00" onkeyup="sum();">Yes (two-color) - $7.00</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_03" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_03"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_04_numbers_back" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_04_numbers_back.majors_04.value=this.value">
<option value="">Select Back Number Options</option>
<option value="8" onkeyup="sum();">One-color - $8</option>
<option value="12" onkeyup="sum();">Two-color - $12</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_04" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_04"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_05_player_name" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_05_player_name.majors_05.value=this.value">
<option value="">Select Player Name Options</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">None - $0</option>
<option value="2.25" onkeyup="sum();">Player Last Name - $2.25</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_05" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_05"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_06_patch" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_06_patch.majors_06.value=this.value">
<option value="">Little League Patch?</option>
<option value="1" onkeyup="sum();">Yes - $1</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">No - $0</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_06" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_06"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_07_youth_or_adult" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_07_youth_or_adult.majors_07.value=this.value">
<option value="">Youth or Adult?</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">Adult (no change)</option>
<option value="-4" onkeyup="sum();">Youth (subtract $4)</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_07" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_07"/>
</form>

Total: $<input type="text" id="result" disabled> Per garment (estimated).

<div id="large-jersey-box-majors" class="hide_come_back_and_rename">
<center><img id="swap" src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/18/1852B/large-54.jpg" height=300></center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at toFixed(2)

Comment: Change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`, then use the suggestion by @Jesse.

Comment: or if you want parseInt parseInt(number*100)/100

Comment: Thanks, guys. Unfortunately I do not know how to plug that into my existing code. Could you offer some examples?

Comment: Well, you're only using `parseInt` in one place...

Comment: I'm not really proficient at writing code like this. I know it probably seems silly to some of the awesome code-writers who are checking this out, but I don't really understand how to put it in there.

Comment: As a question for Stackoverflow, only show the code that is relevant to your question. This does require you reduce your code on your own first, and that's important: typically while reducing your code to the bare minimum that demonstrates your problem you figure out what's wrong and you close the tab without ever asking SO for help. That's a good thing. But, if you still can't figure it out, you now have extremely concise code that doesn't take up hundreds of lines, which people can parse in seconds and help answer without spending time just understanding your question first.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: Thanks. Please understand that I'm doing my best here. I know there are rules and guidelines, and I'm just looking for some help without being in violation of all of them -- which it seems like I do just about every time I post; and people are always really quick to make sure I'm not breaking the rules. You make great points and I will follow that advice going forward.

Comment: Updated original post, as well as Plunker link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 21 of your edited Plunk:

```
).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)||0.00)
```

replace with:

```
).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value)||0.00)
```

And line 22

```
.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
```

replace with:

```
.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Your suggestion did it! Thank you, thank you, thank you! I would up-vote but I'm not eligible yet. Hopefully someone else can come along and do that.

Answer (score 0):

111 line of your Plunker code:

```
).map(e=>parseInt(e.value)||0)
```

replace with:

```
).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)||0.00)
```

Comment: Also a note, you could replace '0.00', if you wanted the default state to have decimals as well. :)

Comment: @Nedim Hozić Thanks! That almost worked. What happened when I replaced the existing code with this updated one is I got the decimals, but then all kinds of extra stuff after that. It also added a leading zero, and now the calculation part doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ally Ripp Would you care to elaborate? Remember that I'm not a "code guy" so you may to really spell it out for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Nedim Hozić, thanks, but that still does not work (for me anyway). I'm doing a straight overwrite, to no avail. I am still getting the leading zero, and the calculations aren't working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@Diego Maia figured this out. This question has been answered.

Replacing/overwriting the lines as illustrated in his response is what was required to make the output display two decimals and for the calculations work correctly.

[Here's the updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UapGq2ei8DUDGAiqHktg?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

form {
display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.sum= () => 
 document.getElementById('result').value=
   Array.from(
     document.querySelectorAll('#majors_01,#majors_02,#majors_03,#majors_04,#majors_05,#majors_06,#majors_07')
   ).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value)||0.00)
   .reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0).toFixed(2)
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="majors_01_jerseys" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select id="majors_01_jerseys" onchange="document.majors_01_jerseys.majors_01.value=this.value;">
<option value="" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/18/1852B/large-54.jpg">Select a Jersey Model</option>
<option value="30.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/17/1751B/large-4P.jpg">Teamwork 1751B</option>
<option value="21.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/17/1755B/large-1.jpg">Teamwork 1755B</option>
<option value="27.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/17/1757B/large-15.jpg">Teamwork 1757B</option>
<option value="27.00" data-src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/18/1825B/large-1.jpg">Teamwork 1825B</option>
<option value="29.90" data-src="http://www.majesticathletic.com/store/productimages/details/10754_columbia_blue_l_z.jpg">Majestic Cool Base 684Y</option>
<option value="32.54" data-src="http://www.uesports.com/imgrep/12107/image-440-0.jpg">UE B0173 (fully braided)</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_01" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_01"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#majors_01_jerseys").on('change', function(){
    $("#swap").attr("src", $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-src"));
});
</script>

</form>

<form name="majors_02_graphics" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_02_graphics.majors_02.value=this.value">
<option value="">Select Front Graphics Options</option>
<option value="2.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Silkscreen (one-color) - $2.75</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Silkscreen (two-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="4.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Silkscreen (three-color) - $4.75</option>
<option value="2.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Silkscreen (one-color) - $2.75</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Silkscreen (two-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="4.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Silkscreen (three-color) - $4.75</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Heat Press (one-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="7.50" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Heat Press (two-color) - $7.50</option>
<option value="11.25" onkeyup="sum();">Left Chest Heat Press (three-color) - $11.25</option>
<option value="3.75" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Heat Press (one-color) - $3.75</option>
<option value="7.50" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Heat Press (two-color) - $7.50</option>
<option value="11.25" onkeyup="sum();">Wordmark Heat Press (three-color) - $11.25</option>
</select>

$<input type="text" id="majors_02" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_02"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_03_numbers_front" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_03_numbers_front.majors_03.value=this.value">
<option value="">Front Numbers?</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">No - $0</option>
<option value="2.25" onkeyup="sum();">Yes (one-color) - $2.25</option>
<option value="7.00" onkeyup="sum();">Yes (two-color) - $7.00</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_03" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_03"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_04_numbers_back" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_04_numbers_back.majors_04.value=this.value">
<option value="">Select Back Number Options</option>
<option value="8" onkeyup="sum();">One-color - $8</option>
<option value="12" onkeyup="sum();">Two-color - $12</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_04" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_04"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_05_player_name" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_05_player_name.majors_05.value=this.value">
<option value="">Select Player Name Options</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">None - $0</option>
<option value="2.25" onkeyup="sum();">Player Last Name - $2.25</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_05" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_05"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_06_patch" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_06_patch.majors_06.value=this.value">
<option value="">Little League Patch?</option>
<option value="1" onkeyup="sum();">Yes - $1</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">No - $0</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_06" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_06"/>
</form>

<form name="majors_07_youth_or_adult" onsubmit="CheckForm()">
<select onchange="document.majors_07_youth_or_adult.majors_07.value=this.value">
<option value="">Youth or Adult?</option>
<option value="0" onkeyup="sum();">Adult (no change)</option>
<option value="-4" onkeyup="sum();">Youth (subtract $4)</option>
</select>
$<input type="text" id="majors_07" onkeyup="sum()" name="majors_07"/>
</form>

Total: $<input type="text" id="result" disabled> Per garment (estimated).

<div id="large-jersey-box-majors" class="hide_come_back_and_rename">
<center><img id="swap" src="http://www.teamworkathletic.com/media/img/product/18/1852B/large-54.jpg" height=300></center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Awesome! Thank you!